# How to check whether a text input is disabled in Casper.js?

Tags: javascript, casperjs, disabled-input

I am writing a Casper.js test. I need to check whether an input field is `disabled`.

```
casper.waitForSelector("input[id='myid']",
    function success() {
        ...
    },
    function fail() {
        ...
    });

    ...
```

Retrieving the field is not an issue, but what about the disabled test?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure if Casper.js supports this, but you should be able to use the [`:disabled` pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:disabled) in your selector and let the DOM handle it for you.

If that works correctly, your code would simply become:

```
casper.waitForSelector("input[id='myid']:disabled",
function success() {
    ...
},
function fail() {
    ...
});

...
```

and you will only receive the element if it is disabled. If you need the inverse, there is a corresponding [`:enabled`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:enabled) that should be able to do that.

Comment: Yes, PhantomJS (and CasperJS) support `:disabled` as well as `:enabled`.

Comment: If the element being enabled (or disabled, whichever you don't want) can be considered a failure, then this method should work. Otherwise, Artjom's answer is probably better, as it gives you a boolean value.

Comment: I can see a type of script where your suggestion would be cleaner. It depends on the use case. For example if the disabledness (?) is an indicator for some process on the page, then your suggestion is better, because the two resulting actions can be directly called. My suggestion would be error prone (and awkward to fix) when the state change is actually needed to be captured. On the other hand my suggestion is slightly better when the condition has to be asserted.

Answer (score 2):

You don't show how you retrieve the element, but I assume that you use the casper API without `evaluate`. You have to use the `evaluate`, because `disabled` is a property of a DOM element and the existing casper API only provides convenience functions which retrieve the attribute:

```
function success() {
    var disabled = this.evaluate(function(selector){
        return !!document.querySelector(selector).disabled;
    }, "input#myid");
}
```

If the element is not changed since the page load, you can also use [`getElementInfo`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#getelementinfo):

```
function success() {
    var disabled = !!this.getElementInfo("input#myid").attributes.disabled;
}
```

Comment: Are you saying that if the element is modified after the page is loaded, I MUST use evaluate to capture those changes? In other words, a simple waitForSelector() won't do the job?

Comment: Yes, because `getElementInfo` only captures the attributes of an element and not the properties. Usually, the developers don't care about the attribute, but only set the property. You still would need `waitForSelector` if the element is loaded/added dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

How's this.  Simple synchronous, unobtrusive.

```
var x = require('casper').selectXPath;

if (!casper.exists(x('//div[@class="item_size"]/input[@disabled]'))){ //!disabled
 xpath = '//div[@class="item_size"]//li[1]/label'
 var size = casper.fetchText(x(xpath)).trim();
 casper.echo(size);
 sizes.push(size)
}
```